# Did 80% of Soviet males born in 1923 die in WWII?

Tags: history, world-war-ii, soviet-union

I found this fact on [OMG Facts](http://www.omgfacts.com/lists/9785/80-of-Soviet-males-born-in-1923-died-in-WWII):

> **80% of Soviet males born in 1923 died in WWII.**
>
> Not surprisingly, Russia was the country with the highest WW2 causalities, with over 21 million.

I can't find any source for the figure beyond fact-list websites. Is this true?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) While this is a perfectly good question here, and it will probably get a good answer, you might have more luck at history.stackexchange.com, as more history buffs hang around there.

Comment: For anyone who has access to Russian-language sources, Wikipedia's article [World War II casualties of the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties_of_the_Soviet_Union) looks like a good starting point.  A back-of-the-envelope calculation from the numbers there shows about a 30% death rate, but changing assumptions could shift it considerably up or down.

Comment: For comparison, [total number deaths in WW2 by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties): USA 0.3% of total population; UK 1%; Germany 11%; USSR 14% (Russia 13%, Ukraine 16%).

Comment: Does this include being shot by NKVD between 1937 and 1945?

Comment: "... in WWII" presumably means death, from any cause, in the 1941-1945 time frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That seems high? 
I expect "80%" possible and even plausible, but the one piece of data which I'm going to present (below) suggests "40%",

There's data referenced in [Uncounted Costs of World War II:
The Effect of Changing Sex Ratios on Marriage
and Fertility of Russian Women](http://web.williams.edu/Economics/faculty/brainerd-rfwomen.pdf), which says there ended up being a male/female sex ratio of 0.6 to 1 for that cohort.

IMO that implies that "80%" is a bit high (because 80% would imply a 0.2 to 1 ratio assuming no women died).

On page 5,

> Russian demographers calculate that the probability of surviving
>   between 1941 and 1946 for men aged 25 to 34 fell from .96 – the probability in the absence of
>   the war based on 1940 mortality rates – to .61 (Andreev et. al. 1993).

And

> While women in the prewar Soviet Union already contended with sex ratios below 1.0 – likely
>   due to the revolutions of 1905 and 1917, World War I (1914-1917), civil war (1918-1922) and
>   the political purges of the 1930s, all of which disproportionately affected men – the sex ratio fell
>   dramatically for individuals born around 1925, from .91 to .65 for the 20-29 age group.

But these are numbers for Russia, not the whole Soviet Union:

> The data and figures in this and following sections are for the Russian republic (the RSFSR)
>   rather than the Soviet Union as a whole, since the empirical analysis uses Russian census data and
>   primarily focuses on the Russian republic.

It's easy to imagine most of the men of fighting age dying, in places like [Leningrad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Leningrad#Effect_on_the_city).

Russia accounts for maybe [half the population of the USSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_Soviet_Union#Population), the next largest being the Ukraine. Given that there was mass conscription I'm going to guess that Russian losses were representative of those of the USSR as a whole (though it also wouldn't surprise me if Ukrainian casualties were higher).

Still I don't see how or from where to infer 80%. Perhaps (I speculate) the pre-war army was nearly annihilated, and that every man born in 1923 was (aged 18 in 1941 and) a conscript in that army:

> The surprise attack on
>   the woefully unprepared Red Army led to devastating losses for the Soviet Union in the early
>   phase of the war: within the first six months, the Red Army had lost nearly 5 million men – the
>   size of the Soviet Union’s entire prewar army – and had lost territory equal to the size of the
>   United States between the East Coast and Springfield, Illinois (Glantz 2005).
>
> The Soviet Union mobilized all possible resources in its subsequent fight for survival and
>   ultimate victory. The need for manpower dictated a significant loosening of the age and
>   nationality restrictions on conscription of Soviet citizens; it is reported that men “well under” the
>   age of 18 and exceeding 55 years of age were conscripted into the Red Army, with Russians and
>   non-Russians alike required to serve (Glantz 2005).

---

One anomaly that is not explained is there is an apparent discontinuity in the graph for Figure 3 on page 30:

[image]

But perhaps that's not proof that the numbers are 'off the scale' then, but rather it's because there are no census numbers for that date-range ("at age 20"), because it's while the war is actually happening.

Comment: This is a great start to an answer, but the "assuming no women died" part is way off. A ["sizable number of women served in the {Soviet} army"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_women_in_World_War_II), mostly medics but also many front-line combat roles like gunners, snipers and pilots. Civilian women also suffered terribly from events like the Siege of Stalingrad and other hostile advances, and food/medical shortages, etc. If you can find a decent estimate of the male : female death ratio  or deaths among Soviet women, it could lift the 40% substantially

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what version of this claim you read, they will state 80% died "in WWII" or "did not survive WWII".  Either way, the implication is 80% of the male population of 1923 was killed during WWII implying some colossal slaughter.  It turns out the slaughter had happened long before.

[Mark Harrison did research and a write up on this very statement](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/markharrison/entry/was_the_soviet/).  This conclusion was that half that population was already dead when the war broke out from infant mortality, disease, famine, and Stalin's purges.

> Here's the numbers I worked from on the programme(in thousands, rounded to the nearest hundred thousand). Each of the lines is sourced below.
>
> ```
> Males born in the Soviet Union in 1923: 3,400
> Infant (0-1) mortality: 800
> Childhood (1-18) mortality, famine, and terror: 800
> Surviving to 1941: 1,800
> Wartime mortality: 700
> Surviving to 1946: 1,100
> ```
>
> The Buzzfeed claim is overstated, although not by a wide margin. Around two thirds (more exactly, 68%) of the original 1923 male birth cohort did not survive World War II. But the war is not the most important reason for the poor survival rate; almost half of them died before the war broke out.

One can say 40% of Soviet males born in 1923 *who survived to see WWII* died in WWII.  Still pretty damn brutal.

Comment: died "in WWII" means literally died, fighting the war. It doesn't mean the more general "died during WWII" or "did not survive WWII".